# Prerequisites for Morita's Geometry of Differential Forms

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, book-recommendation

What are the prerequisites for *Geometry of Differential Forms* by Morita? Will I be better off reading a calculus on manifolds book first, like Spivak? Also, do I need to know any topology before?

Comment: Morita is pretty much self contained , you need to know pointset topology and multivariable calculus. It also requires good mathematical maturity.